# iOS Push: Can't find problematic token

Tags: python, ios, apple-push-notifications, token

I am having a problem when sending pushes. I am using python and the apns-client lib to send pushes. My tokens are stored on mysql and since the last few weeks I have been seeing this exception when sending pushes:

```
ERROR: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

Which lead me to think that there's a malformed token on the db. Now, how can I check which token is wrong?

I tried the following on my tokens (I read it somewhere on the internet):

```
for token in tokens:
    try:
        token.decode('hex')
    except:
        print token
```

but no exception is thrown at all.

any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: This will not throw an exception; it prints the offending token and continues.  Is that your problem?  If you require the exception as well, try adding "raise" after the print statement.  Also note that your "except" line is too general for Python BKM.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted, to print the problematic tokens. And I know that except is too general, but I wanted to catch all exceptions because the error that I wrote is coming from the apns-client lib, so I don't exactly what type of exception is throwing

Answer (score 0):

Then let's try this to close the question:

```
for token in tokens:
    try:
        token.decode('hex')
    except Exception as e:
        print token, type(e)
        raise e
```

Does that get everything you want?

Comment: Thanks, but that's the problem, token.decode('hex') works fine and never throws any exception. My issue is that I don't know how to properly check if a token has a valid format or not, that's why my initial code never prints anything.